# Options for WiFi coverage to share multiple servers across home on a single network

Tags: wireless-networking

I have two machines dedicated as servers, each with different platforms, in my house, which used to be tied to my internet router via ethernet in the same room and on the same network as every device around my house that would access them over WiFi.

I moved to a two story "renovation" home that forced me to keep the router upstairs where I only have room for one server, the other must move downstairs to the office I'm building but in that room it and all other WiFi devices barely get a signal which shorts out and on if you're lucky. Plus no signal to the backyard which my wife hates when we barbecue or whatever.

I can program, but I'm no good with IT and I hope you can help. The question is: How do I get access to the same network created by my main router throughout the house on WiFi and to the backyard? I looked at options and some seem (extenders?) to generate secondary networks, but I need all my devices connected and accessible... What's my best option?

Edit: I should also specify I have no idea how mesh networks work, and I need streaming wireless capabilities across the board. I can't run Ethernet either.

Answer (score 0):

Not too many details in your question so I can only give a general answer:

Not sure what you looked up but meshed network systems don't generate "secondary nets" it's all the same LAN just as if would be wired. If you install meshed networks the node connect to each other via WLAN so there is no need for a cable. If you need high performance I would consider a Ubiquity system, or get a cheap one from Google, TP-Link, etc.